# how i can reverse transform in css dynamically by js

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

just i bought a WordPress theme and I make some changes to get a proper experience, so when I turned to body{direction: rtl;} it appears like this
[enter image description here][1]

so, after 5 hours search about this, i found it but I can't handle the problem
[This is the file who can't know what to do][2]

so when I edit this from WordPress CSS editor... it's still like this when I open the side menu
[notice that in developer tools][3]
and this is when I close it...
[enter image description here][4]
So what's the problem?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Try to `transform: translate(-100%, 0)` to completely translate the sidebar out of the screen on `x` dimention.

Comment: its dynamically change so i can't trigger it